# Can numpy arrays be plugged into functions in python?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, simulation

I have a function (equation2) that returns Nf (or N), which stands for the final population size. Right now I want to simulate 100 years with (r=0.1, K=100, and N0=10), and plot out N as a function of t (year) (the second part of the code). However, python returns a value error (`The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`) every time I run the code. It seems like I can't put an array into equation2 but every other time I tried assigning my x-value as a numpy array it just uses one single value of the array every time to go into the function. Therefore, I'm very confused. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
def equation2(r,K,N0,t):
    i=0
    N=N0
    while i<=t:
        if t==0:
            return N0
        else:
            Nf=N+(r*(1-N/K)*N)
            N=Nf 
            i=i+1
    return Nf

import numpy as np
r=0.1
K=100
N0=10
t=np.linspace(0,100,101)
N=equation2(r,K,N0,t)
plt.plot(t,N)
```

Comment: You can't do a test like `if t==0` if `t` is an array.

Comment: Please write a title that summarizes the problem you're having. See [ask] for tips on that. You can [edit].

Comment: You have to decide for yourself what is supposed to happen when `t` is an array.

Comment: @hpaulj Actually the error occurs at `while i<=t`

Comment: Do not change the topic of the question. I have rolled it back. If you have a new question, you can [ask a new question](/questions/ask), but I think the answer is that matplotlib automatically adjusts the scale. I mean, have you even tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Why would the year be an array when it should be a scalar?

It looks like you actually want to map `equation2` over `t`, like this:

```
N = [equation2(r, K, N0, year) for year in t]
```

Comment: yes! I did not realize I can do "for y in t" since t is a scalar (I thought that would be iterating through a scalar).

Comment: @xin Scalar? My whole point is that `t` is **not** a scalar

Comment: hmm. but isn't `t` originally entered into the function as a scalar?

Comment: @xin Oh wait, which `t` are you referring to? It's confusing because you've [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global name with the parameter name.

Comment: I see. I guess what I meant in my comment is the original `t` that is one of the parameters of the function (which would be a scalar?), but you're talking about the global name `t` that is part of your code? In my original code, I was trying to account for the fact that I want to simulate 100 years (so t=0 to t=100), and would change it to simulate 1000 years in my next attempt. That's why I tried to make it an array (I don't know if you have noticed that part).

Comment: @xin I'm really not sure what you're talking about, but I did just notice that `equation2()` does a reduction, so are you trying to have it do an accumulation instead? (c.f. [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).) That'd make sense, but you'd need to totally refactor it, and I'm not sure how to do an accumulation in NumPy. I'm a bit out of my depth tbh.